# How to implement a Service layer in Spring MVC stateless application (without DB)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

There is an application that receives some input parameters, makes some calculations and return result (like web service), without persistence layer. Below is a very simple example of what I need.

Suppose, I have an entity `Circle` in a *model* layer:

```
package com.example.model;

public class Circle {
    private double radius;    
    // constructor, getter and setter
}
```

And a `CircleController` in the *controller* layer:

```
package com.example.controller;
// imports

@Controller
public class CircleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/circle")
    public String circleDetails(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("circle", new Circle());
        return "circle_form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "circleResult", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String calcCircleDetails(Circle circle, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "circle_form";
        }
        return "circle_result";
    }
}
```

With some view app accepts parameters from user (in this case only `radius`) and returns the result, let's say, `square` and `perimeter`. The algorithms for calculating that values are:

```
public static double calculateSquare(Circle circle) {
    return Math.PI * circle.getRadius() * circle.getRadius();
}

public static double calculatePerimeter(Circle circle) {
    return 2 * Math.PI * circle.getRadius();
}
```

Following the best practices, I want to keep the structure clean and separated by all logical layers (e.g., database, dao, service, controller, etc.).
I want to **add a Service layer** between the controller and the model, e.g. `com.example.service.CircleService`.

If I had a persistence layer, I would implement the *repository* layer, inject the `CircleRepository` object to *service* layer and make there my business logic, and finally inject this `CircleService` object to my *controller layer*. But in that case things should be easier.

What is the most effective way to implement such design in Spring MVC application to achieve the best usability, flexibility, testability, scalability and code readability?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm curious about. Did you manage to find an answer somehow?

Comment: @hamahama Didn't get the answer about the best practice. But actually at that time, I used a controller with GET method there, where I validated the form with BindingResult and call the service layer with business logic / algorithm. Then I returned the result back to the controller, added it (and some other attributes) to the ModelMap and passed those values to render a view with Thymeleaf. Just MVC.